# Write to file in ARM Assembly

Tags: linux, assembly, file-io, arm, raspbian

I'm attempting to write the integer contents of a register to a text file in ARM Assembly. 
I have been reading with little success - I have deduced from reading the technical manual I will require some SWI instruction, but I cannot for the life of me find a concrete example of how to do this.

Operating system is Raspbian running on Pi B model.

Thank you in advance for any help, if you require any clarifications please let me know!

**EDIT :** To clarify, I am assembling and executing my code successfully using GCC. I want to store the values of my data registers to a text file.

**Example :**

```
.global main
.func main

main:
    mov r1, #19
    mov r2, #11
    add r0, r1, r2
    bx lr
```

In the above case, r0 would hold the value 30. I want to write that value to a text file.

Comment: It is much easier to get help when you ask concrete questions.

Comment: @auselen - what more could I add? Assume a simple assembly program which stores the value 3 in r0. I now want to write the contents of r0 to a txt file. I am not sure what else you would like, but please tell me.

Comment: Writing a '3' to a file is not as writing any integer. Are you able to write ~`itoa` in C? Do you know how to write '3' to a text file? Why not to just STDOUT? Do you know the difference between a file and STDOUT? Are you able to use the tools to produce an executable from an assembly file? Since I don't know your foundations, I don't know where to start answering.

Comment: Anyway I added answer to other question: http://stackoverflow.com/a/28818270/1163019

Comment: @auselen,  I haven't written any C, my background is in Java & C# and this is my first dabble into ARM assembly, so thank you for taking the time to reply to me. I understand the idea behind STDOUT and yes, I am able to use the tools to produce an executable from the assembly files, and have done so successfully so far. What I would like to do, and as of yet have been unable to find any information on, is storing the contents of the data registers into a file on disk at the end of execution. Is this achievable with STDOUT in assembly?

Edit: I should also add i'm using GNU Compiler. Thanks!

Comment: Assembly language itself has no concept of anything beyond instructions, registers and memory addresses. Since you'd essentially end up implementing `fopen()`, `fwrite()`, `fclose()` and possibly various other bits of the C library that's already right there, there's a strong argument for just linking the C library and calling its I/O functions directly (learning the details of calling conventions in the process). Of course, that's not to say you _shouldn't_ learn the details of the OS interface, just that it's possibly something that can wait.

Comment: @Notlikethat - that seems to make alot of sense. I was unaware you could call C functions from within Assembly. is there a definitive source/tutorial for this, or could you recommend something to get me started? Thank you again. If you want to write that as an answer i'll happily mark it as such.

Comment: not necessarily fopen right? open should do ok.

Answer (score 0):

I did give this a try, thinking about things you need to know beforehand. Of course there are many ways to utilize assembly programming but I aimed for no help from the compiler or libraries.

- Be able to use toolchain correctly
- Linker expects a `_start` symbol
- Define a string, address it
- Constants for `O_WRONLY`, `O_CREAT`
- How to encode permission
- Find out call signatures of `open`, `write`, `fsync`, `close`, `exit`
- How to make a syscall
- Some kind of memory management, I used stack
- Pointers
- ASCII representation of a digit
- Load / Store of registers, addressing modes
- How to debug! Funny thing I started thinking this should be straight forward only to find out hard way that you need to call `fsync` before exiting the process to ask kernel for flushing. Probably `O_DIRECT | O_SYNC` is an easier choice.

  ```
  $ as open_e.s -o open_e.o
  $ ld open_e.o -o open_e
  $ cat open_e.s
  .global _start

  _start:
  @open syscall 
  ldr r0, =filename
  mov r1, #0101 @ O_WRONLY | O_CREAT
  ldr r2, =0666 @ permissions
  mov r7, #5 @ 5 is system call number for open
  svc #0
  cmp r0, #0
  blt exit

  @r0 contains fd (file descriptor, an integer)
  mov r5, r0

  @write syscall
  @use stack as buffer
  sub sp, #8 @ stack is full descending, this is how we leave some space
  mov r1, #'4'
  strb r1, [sp]
  mov r1, #'2'
  strb r1, [sp, #1]
  mov r1, #'\n'
  strb r1, [sp, #2]
  mov r1, sp
  mov r2, #3
  mov r7, #4 @ 4 is write
  svc #0

  @fsync syscall
  mov r0, r5
  mov r7, #118
  svc #0

  @close syscall
  mov r7, #6 @ 6 is close
  svc #0

  exit:
  mov r0, #0
  mov r7, #1
  svc #0

  .data
  .align 2
  filename: .asciz "out.txt"
  ```